# Accessing a variable from a class object apart of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I have a class which is an extended `JPanel` with different swing components like text fields, checkboxes etc.

I'm trying to access the constructor's parameters from the class objects I have instantiated and added to the `secondPanel` JPannel. 
 For example the cost, name, etc.

```java
secondPanel.add(new ProductDesign("GPU: RTX 2070",649.99,"src/resources/rtx_card_2070.png"));
secondPanel.add(new ProductDesign("CPU: Intel i7-8700k",469.99,"src/resources/i7-8700k.png"));
secondPanel.add(new ProductDesign("CPU: Intel i5-9600k",309.99,"src/resources/i5_9600k.png"));
```

I iterate through the second pannel and I am able to get the state of some of the swing components, in this case I can get values of the selectBox with the method `getAccessibleChild(3)`.

```java
for (Component secondPanel : secondPanel.getComponents()) {
    ProductDesign.detect(secondPanel.getAccessibleContext().getAccessibleChild(3));
}
```

However, I'd also like to be able to get the values that each class object has.  For example the cost, or name, from the class constructor. Is there a way to do this with this setup?

```java
package main;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import javax.accessibility.Accessible;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ProductDesign extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8719763672439672064L;

    final static int checkX = 130;
    final static int checkY = 58;

    ProductDesign(String name, double cost, String img){
        JLabel productIcon = new JLabel();
        productIcon.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 80);
        productIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        this.add(productIcon);

        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel(name);
        nameLabel.setBounds(130,-30,400,100);
        nameLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        nameLabel.setFont(new Font(name, Font.BOLD, 20));
        this.add(nameLabel);

        JLabel priceTag = new JLabel("$"+cost);
        priceTag.setBounds(130,28,100,40);
        priceTag.setForeground(Color.white);
        this.add(priceTag);

        JCheckBox confirmItem = new JCheckBox();
        confirmItem.setBounds(130,58,25,25);
        this.add(confirmItem);

        JLabel quantityText = new JLabel("Qty:");
        quantityText.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        quantityText.setBounds(160,60,60,20);
        this.add(quantityText);

        JTextArea productQuantity = new JTextArea();
        productQuantity.setBounds(190, 60, 60, 20);
        this.add(productQuantity);

        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBackground(new Color(100,100,110));
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(new BasicStroke(3.0f), new Color(110,110,120)));
    }

    public static void detect(Accessible accessible) {
        if (((AbstractButton) accessible).isSelected()) {
            ((AbstractButton) accessible).setLocation(checkX-5, checkY);

        }
        else {
            ((AbstractButton) accessible).setLocation(checkX, checkY);
        }

    }
}
```

EDITS:

I added an action listener which is now within the `ProductDesign` class

```java
package main;

import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.accessibility.Accessible;
import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

public class ProductDesign extends JPanel{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8719763672439672064L;

    final static int checkX = 130;
    final static int checkY = 58;

    String name;
    Double cost;
    int count;



    ProductDesign(String name, double cost, String img){
        JLabel productIcon = new JLabel();
        productIcon.setBounds(10, 10, 100, 80);
        productIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
        this.add(productIcon);

        JLabel nameLabel = new JLabel(name);
        nameLabel.setBounds(130,-30,400,100);
        nameLabel.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        nameLabel.setFont(new Font(name, Font.BOLD, 20));
        this.add(nameLabel);

        JLabel priceTag = new JLabel("$"+cost);
        priceTag.setBounds(130,28,100,40);
        priceTag.setForeground(Color.white);
        this.add(priceTag);

        JCheckBox confirmItem = new JCheckBox();
        confirmItem.setBounds(130,58,25,25);
        this.add(confirmItem);

        confirmItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                if (confirmItem.isSelected()) {
                    confirmItem.setLocation(checkX-5, checkY);
                }
                else {
                    confirmItem.setLocation(checkX, checkY);
                }
            }
        });

        JLabel quantityText = new JLabel("Qty:");
        quantityText.setForeground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
        quantityText.setBounds(160,60,60,20);
        this.add(quantityText);

        JTextArea productQuantity = new JTextArea();
        productQuantity.setBounds(190, 60, 60, 20);
        this.add(productQuantity);

        this.setLayout(null);
        this.setBackground(new Color(100,100,110));
        this.setBorder(BorderFactory.createStrokeBorder(new BasicStroke(3.0f), new Color(110,110,120)));

        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public double getCost() {
        return cost;
    }
}
```

From this action listener, what is the correct syntax to use those non-static methods to get the cost/name and count of the specific instance of the checkbox that was selected?

Comment: *"I have a class which is an extended `JPanel`.."* .. **Why?** Or more completely: why extend `JPanel` rather than use an instance of a standard panel, when there is no good case for doing so. and it causes problems like locking controls into an inaccessible form (like right now)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create instance variables for the parameters
2. Save the parameters in your instance variables
3. Create `getName()`, `getCost()` methods as needed to access the data.

At the start of your class:

```
private String name;
private int cost;
...
```

In the constructor:

```
this.name = name;
this.cost = cost;
...
```

Custom methods in your class:

```
public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

...
```

Edit:

The code in the ActionListener for the "confirmItem" checkbox might be something like:

```
JCheckBox checkBox = (JCheckBoox)event.getSource();
ProductDesign pd = (ProductDesign)checkbox.getParent();
String name = pd.getName();
```

Comment: How can I call those methods correctly so I can get the name of an instance that matches a certain state? For example, in the `detect` method, a button is selected and I'd like to get the value of that specific instance's cost/name.

Comment: *a button is selected*  You add an ActionListener to the check box. When the button is clicked, you can get the parent panel of the check box and cast it to ProductDesign. Then you can access the custom methods.

Comment: So how can I actually access those methods?

Comment: What don't you understand? 1) Do you know how to write an ActionListener? 2) Do you know how to cast classes? 3) Do you know how to use the `getParent()` method? See edit.

Comment: I am using an instance of the `Accessible` class to get a reference to the selected button. So I'm not sure how to include these methods within the `detect` method I included above.

Comment: *I am using an instance of the Accessible class* - I have no idea why. *how to include these methods within the detect method* - I also have no idea why you have a detect method. I guess I have no idea what you are doing. Code should be written in the ActionListener.

Comment: I edited my post. I included code I used for an actionListener as well as the question I have. – Hydra 1 hour ago   Delete

Comment: Your question asked `I'd also like to be able to get the values that each class object has. For example the cost, or name,`  Why do you have code playing with the location? I gave you 3 lines of code that I think should be in the ActionListener. You need another statement for the cost. Also, note that when saving the parameter values to instance variiables this is typically done at the start of the constructor so people know you intend to use these value later in the class.